# SQL Query returns unknown error without any further information

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I have tried to process select query.
The query works fine in DB browser for SQLite.

However, it returns error when I apply it on C.

```
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                                    "SELECT _id, name1, name2, name3, num1, type1, num2, typ2, " \
                                    "num3, typ3, num4, type4, num5, type5, " \
                                    "instr(name1||name2||name3, ?), " \
                                    "instr(num1, ?), instr(num2, ?), instr(num3, ?), " \
                                    "instr(num4, ?), instr(num5, ?), " \
                                    "unicode(substr(name1|| name2|| name3, 1, 1)) " \
                                    "FROM table1 " \
                                    "WHERE (name1||name2||name3 LIKE ? " \
                                    "OR name1||name3||name3 LIKE ? " \
                                    "OR REPLACE(name1||name2||name3, ',', '') LIKE ? " \
                                    "OR REPLACE(name1||name2||name3, ',', '') LIKE ? " \
                                    "OR num1 LIKE ? OR name2 LIKE ? " \
                                    "OR num3 LIKE ? OR num4 LIKE ? OR num5 LIKE ?) " \
                                    "ORDER BY CASE " \
                                    "WHEN ((instr(name1, ?) IS 1) AND name3 != '') THEN 1 " \
                                    "WHEN ((instr(name3, ?) IS 1) AND name1 = '') THEN 2 " \
                                    "WHEN ((instr(name1, ?) IS 1) AND name3 = '') THEN 2 " \
                                    "WHEN (instr(name1||' '||name2||' '||name3, ?) IS 1) THEN 3 " \
                                    "WHEN (instr(name1||', '||name2||', '||name3, ?) IS 1) THEN 3 " \
                                    "ELSE 4 END, UPPER(name1||name2||name3) LIMIT 1000 " \
                                    "collate KOREA",
                                    -1,
                                    &main_stmt,
                                    0
                                    );
            char LIKEsearchWord1[52];
            char LIKEsearchWord2[52];

            memset(LIKEsearchWord1, '\0', 52);
            memset(LIKEsearchWord2, '\0', 52);

            LIKEsearchWord1[0] = '%';
            LIKEsearchWord2[0] = '%';

            strcat(LIKEsearchWord1, searchWord1);
            strcat(LIKEsearchWord2, searchWord2);
            
            strcat(LIKEsearchWord1, "%");
            strcat(LIKEsearchWord2, "%");

           if(result == SQLITE_OK)
           {
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 0, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 1, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 2, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 3, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 4, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 5, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 6, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 7, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 8, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 9, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 10, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 11, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 12, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 13, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 14, searchWord2, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 15, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 16, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 17, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 18, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
             sqlite3_bind_text(main_stmt, 19, searchWord1, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

             result = sqlite3_step(main_stmt);
             if(result != SQLITE_OK)
             {
               printf(SQL error: "%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
             }
            }
```

Above code is what I have tested in C.
The words for LIKE are correct with both % at start and end.

However, the result of sqlite3_stpe(main_stmt) is unkown error without any further information.
I don't know what is wrong.

Even though I make the query one line without backslash, it has same error.

Comment: Do you check to see if `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` succeeded?

Comment: @Shawn Yes I missed the code but it is already checked before bind the datas

Comment: Speaking of binding, parameter indexes start at 1.

Comment: And you might want to use named/numbered parameters so you only have to bind two values.

Comment: @Shawn what means binding two values?